# io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0 throws while invoking PacketByteBuf.readFloat in minecraft 1.16.5

Tags: java, netty, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I am trying to create a temperature system in my mod, and I synchronize temperature data (2 floats) with Fabric Networking API. Packets are created with these codes.

```
// Temperature.java
private float ambient;
private float biome;

public PacketByteBuf createBuffer() {
    PacketByteBuf buf = PacketByteBufs.create();
    buf.writeFloat(ambient);
    buf.writeFloat(biome);
    return buf;
}

public void loadBuffer(PacketByteBuf buf) {
    this.ambient = buf.readFloat();
    this.biome = buf.readFloat();
}

public void copyFieldsTo(Temperature that) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(that, "that");
    that.ambient = this.ambient;
    that.biome = this.biome;
}
```

Netty always throws "io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0" in loadBuffer method. Data are not synchronized, but packets are received.
These are codes to send packets and receive packets.

```
// In a mixin to ServerPlayerEntity
@Unique
private Temperature rmc$temperature;
@Unique
private Temperature rmc$syncedTemperature;
@Inject(method = "playerTick", at = @At(value = "INVOKE",
            target = "Lnet/minecraft/server/network/ServerPlayerEntity;getHealth()F",
            shift = At.Shift.BEFORE, ordinal = 0))
private void syncRMCData(CallbackInfo ci) {
    TemperatureUtil.update(rmc$temperature, self);//Update temperature data
    if (!rmc$temperature.equals(rmc$syncedTemperature)) {
         ServerPlayNetworking.send(self, TemperatureUtil.PACKET_ID, rmc$temperature.createBuffer());
         rmc$temperature.copyFieldsTo(rmc$syncedTemperature);
    }
}
// In client mod initializer
ClientPlayNetworking.registerGlobalReceiver(TemperatureUtil.PACKET_ID,
        (client, handler, buf, responseSender) -> client.execute(
                () -> ((TemperatureAccess) client.player).getTemperature()
                        .loadBuffer(buf)));
// TemperatureAccess is an interface implemented by a mixin to ClientPlayerEntity
```

This is the stack trace:

```
[13:22:34] [main/FATAL] (Minecraft) Error executing task on Client
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureAccessible(AbstractByteBuf.java:1417) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1403) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readByte(AbstractByteBuf.java:707) ~[netty-all-4.1.25.Final.jar:4.1.25.Final]
    at net.minecraft.network.PacketByteBuf.readByte(PacketByteBuf.java:1260) ~[minecraft-1.16.5-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.5+build.10-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.network.PacketByteBuf.readVarInt(PacketByteBuf.java:483) ~[minecraft-1.16.5-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.5+build.10-v2.jar:?]
    at io.github.asablock.rmc.temperature.Temperature.loadBuffer(Temperature.java:50) ~[main/:?]
    at io.github.asablock.rmc.client.ClientReasonableMCMod.lambda$onInitializeClient$2(ClientReasonableMCMod.java:57) ~[main/:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ThreadExecutor.executeTask(ThreadExecutor.java:136) [minecraft-1.16.5-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.5+build.10-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ReentrantThreadExecutor.executeTask(ReentrantThreadExecutor.java:22) [minecraft-1.16.5-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.5+build.10-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ThreadExecutor.runTask(ThreadExecutor.java:109) [minecraft-1.16.5-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.5+build.10-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ThreadExecutor.runTasks(ThreadExecutor.java:97) [minecraft-1.16.5-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.5+build.10-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.render(MinecraftClient.java:1047) [minecraft-1.16.5-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.5+build.10-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.run(MinecraftClient.java:685) [minecraft-1.16.5-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.5+build.10-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:187) [minecraft-1.16.5-mapped-net.fabricmc.yarn-1.16.5+build.10-v2.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[?:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.game.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:234) [fabric-loader-0.11.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:153) [fabric-loader-0.11.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:28) [fabric-loader-0.11.6.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) [dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]
```